# How to decode json with reserved name as key using json_dataclass?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to decode a json I received from an api using `dataclass_json` from the [dataclasses_json](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/) module, however one of the json fields is called `class` which is a python reserved keyword. How can I define them?

```
{'some_var': False,
 'class': '/12345.jpg'}
```

I tried this

```py
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Media:
  some_var: str
  class: str ### error because class is a reserved keyword
```

```py
parsedObject = Media.from_json(jsonString)
```

but get an error due to 'class' being a reserved keyword.

Comment: `file` is not a Python reserved keyword — `keyword.iskeyword('file')` -> `False` — so it sounds like the issue may be due to a bug in the `dataclasses_json` module to me.

Comment: alright, maybe its my mistake, but how about other words like id. class etc

Comment: You'll have to look them up individually in the documentation or use the `keyword` modules (which is often faster). `id` probably isn't, but `class` probably _is_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the original field name as a `field_name` and name your class property differently:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import config, dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Media:
    some_var: str
    the_class: str = field(metadata=config(field_name="class"))
```

Check out the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/), scroll down to "Encode or decode using a different name".

Comment: Reading The Fine Documentation (especially before posting questions here) is _always_ good advice IMO.

Comment: I tried reading the docs, but. I guess should have read in more details. Hope this is useful for other people as well :) thanks

Comment: @Nic: You could automate checking for reserved names by checking all of the dataclass' field names to see if they're in the `keyword.kwlist` — you might even be able to automatically change them when one is found. IMO the `dataclass_json`  decorator should have an option added to it to do the latter…